# Editing appengine static site

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently created a very basic very static site through Google app engine. My question is, if I publish the site, what is required to edit it. What sort of authentication is required when you deploy the site with local files? I might have missed it but does it check an ID from your computer the first time or simply use the project-id in the .yaml file? If I were to deploy it and want to be able to create a different version from another host, what would I need besides the source files?

PS: I will and definitely NEED to go over the doc fully (err semi-fully), just wanted to ask this question which hopefully has a rather trivial answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy it, it will either ask for your username and password, or if you pass the `--oauth2` flag, it will take you through an OAuth flow to authenticate.

(Take a look at `appcfg.py --help` if you are curious about the options available.)

Comment: `--oauth2` is the default these days

Answer (score 0):

Deployment requires the Google Account username and password from someone with permissions to deploy (in your case, probably your admin account).

You can either enter these every time you deploy, or have them stored locally. Check for example here for the Python info: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp